# White space in writing Long fractional equation usign \splitfrac

Tags: equations, mathtools

I am trying to split a long fractional equation using \splitfrac into three lines. The problem is that the three lines are not aligned properly and there is blank space in the third line. Please help!

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq5.13}
\frac{sasd}{asda}=\frac{abcd}{\splitfrac{abcdeefdhsgas+ABDNAKSDALDNCKASJCLAKSCA+}{\splitfrac{ABCDEFGHIJKLAMNAOPQF)+FADGADHSFD}{CC_{D}R_{D}+C_{D}R_{D}+C_{D}R_{D}+C_{D}R_{D})+1}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The three terms in the denominator -- split across three lines via two `\splitfrac` directives -- are quite different in their lengths; in particular, the third line is much shorter than the other two. (Incidentally, your variable names don't really look like `abcdeefdhsgas` and `ABDNAKSDALDNCKASJCLAKSCA`, do they?) Please clarify what you mean by "the three lines are not aligned properly" as well as by "there is a blank space in the third line"

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I can detect neither an alignment problem regarding the three lines in the denominator nor a blank space in the third line.

[image]

When using `\splitfrac` (and its cousin, `\splitdfrac`), *you* are in charge of selecting the line breaks. Depending on the math expressions involved, it may or may not be feasible to make the three lines roughly equal in length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq5.13}
\frac{sasd}{asda}=\frac{abcd}{%
\splitfrac{abcdeefdhsgas+(ABDNAKSDALDNCKASJCLAKSCA\strut}%
          {\splitfrac{{}+ABCDEFGHIJKLAMNAOPQF)+(FADGADHSFD}%
                     {{}\times CC_DR_D+C_DR_D+C_DR_D+C_DR_D)+1}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As you have mentioned that it may not be feasible to make the lines equal in length, is there an alternative around?

Comment: @htkk - It's not possible, I'm afraid, to give actionable formatting advice without knowing more about the equation. Please edit your posting to show the actual fraction expression that's giving you grief.