# Splitting the denominator of fraction into more than two lines

Tags: mathtools

I wish to split the denominator of the following fraction into more than 2 lines. For splitting into two lines, `splitfrac`can be used. But how to split the denominator into three lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq31}
 G_2(s) = \frac{K_pcT_rs+K_p}{\splitfrac{T_pT_rT_pT_ts^4 + \left(T_gT_pT_t + 
 T_gT_pT_r + T_pT_tT_r + T_gT_rT_t\right)s^3}{ +
  \left(T_pT_g + T_tT_g + T_rT_g + T_tT_p + T_rT_p + 
     T_rT_t\right)s^2+\left(T_g + T_r + T_t + T_p\right)s + 1 }}
   \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: as always on this site, please provide a full minimal example instead of a sniplet like this. That makes it a lot easier for others to have a look at your code

Comment: BTW: I would not use `\splitfrac` here, I'd just use the `aligned` environment. Plus those `\left/right` constructions does nothing here.

Comment: Please see the Minimal example

Comment: The aforementioned link deals with breaking of equation into two lines only, while I prefer to break it into more than two lines

Comment: See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386902/280435) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that my answer is based on a personal and aesthetic taste. I prefer to split your denominator with a `matrix` or an `array`. I have also put `geometry` package to have more margin in the page. I think that by minimizing the margins, option that I do not recommend since the printing of the page could crop the formulas, all your formula could be built in a single line.

Here into my MWE I have split the denominator into three lines with `matrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{2}
G_2(s) =\frac{K_pcT_rs+K_p}{\begin{matrix}T_pT_rT_pT_ts^4 +(T_gT_pT_t + 
T_gT_pT_r + T_pT_tT_r + T_gT_rT_t)s^3 &\\+(T_pT_g + T_tT_g + T_rT_g + T_tT_p + T_rT_p + T_rT_t)s^2&\\+(T_g + T_r + T_t + T_p)s + 1\end{matrix}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```